# Kill tcp connections to all backends when any of the haproxy backend gets healthy

Tags: linux, haproxy, failover

I have postgres cluster of 2 nodes behind HAProxy, any of those two can be primary and replica (role is managed by separate system - stolon). I want to force HAProxy to reset tcp connection when primary postgres node comes back. I know there is [on-marked-up shutdown-backup-sessions](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#5.2-on-marked-up) which achieves resetting the connection but it has two requirements:

- It shutdowns down sessions on server marked as backup.
- It only shutdowns sessions when server which is marked up is not in backup state.

In my setup, since any of the two node can be primary or backup state (i.e. I don’t have static allocation of Node A to be primary and Node B to be replica) I am unable to achieve it by setting on-marked-up shutdown-backup-sessions

Is there any other way i can achieve resetting all backend connections when any of the backend node is marked up.

Any help or pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This might help https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-stick-tables/#making-decisions-based-on-stick-tables

Actually they are using sticky table and only single entry will be stored. From same document some references

```
backend mysql
    mode tcp
    stick-table type integer size 1 expire 1d
    stick on int(1)
    server primary 192.168.122.60:3306 check on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
    server backup 192.168.122.61:3306 check backup on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
```

> on-marked-down shutdown-sessions causes HAproxy to close all existing
> connections to a backend when it goes down. Normally HAProxy allows
> existing connections to finish which could result in duplicate primary
> keys if the connections kept working or query timeouts if it didn’t.

Hope this will help, please feel free to add more details to the question based on your experience.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In my case i can't mark primary and backup server statically because at time T1 192.168.122.60 can be primary and at time T2  192.168.122.61 can be the primary which is controlled by another leader-election system. But my requirement is the connection should always go to whosoever is the primary and if primary is absent, then go to the backup and as soon as it comes back up, all connections to backup needs to get killed and client will retry and go back to primary

Comment: `on-marked-down` only applies when the server goes down. In my case, backup server will not go down but primary will come back up.

Comment: Under same doc `This can be undone by cycling the backup node into maintenance mode, or via the Runtime API, when you are ready to have the cluster resume normal operations.` is this not doable in your case? You need to just hit the api stating backup is down if primary is back online?

Comment: Doing it manually by first checking which is the backup and manually marking it into maintenance mode is what I am doing till now. I want to automate that piece.

Comment: I guess you can create cron or daemon at backup node to check master health and perform action? Is it not possible?

Comment: Well if i need to make use of cron (i.e. outside feature set of haproxy) to achieve this, i would have done everything outside haproxy.

Comment: Not everything just need to pass msg backup node is down rest haproxy will take care. Also we shouldn't think all scenarios(business use case) will be covered directly via apps.

Comment: As of haproxy 1.5 there is option on-marked-up. You can use it with action shutdown-backup-sessions on primary mysql like this: "server primary ... check on-marked-up shutdown-backup-sessions". No need to use the stick/stick-table settings.